# Affecting Z Order for UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

Anyone know how to programmatically set the z order of UIImageViews? The order of instancing them will bring the last one instanced closest to the screen front, but how can it be changed at runtime?

Thanks // :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the following if the `UIImageView` is already a subview:

- `bringSubviewToFront`
- `sendSubviewToBack`

or any of the following if you're inserting the `UIImageView` as a subview:

- `insertSubview:atIndex`
- `insertSubview:aboveSubview`
- `insertSubview:belowSubview`

Comment: Note that these methods are all defined on UIView, so you can use them on any kind of view, not just UIImageViews.

Comment: What if you have been adding the views with initWithParent rather than using subviews? Does initWithParent create subviews owned by the parent and kept in an index?

Comment: never heard of initWithParent but yes, you can access them with whatever.subviews

Comment: There is also exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:

If CiNN's answer is good enough, why don't you select it as the answer?  It helps to know what questions are in need of an answer and which aren't.

Comment: As an aside, because this is a standard NSMutableArray operation, this causes the subviews at indices => index to shift up one position. If this was just a resort (that is, the inserted subview was a subview of this same superview before "inserting", the superview's subviews array will not change size, because views can only have one superview, and can only be at one index in the subviews array.